# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'views'

Tags: python, django

I got an error,

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$',django.views.static.serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'views'
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include('UserToken.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^ResultJSON/', include('ResultJSON.urls')),
    url(r'^api/1.0/', include('accounts.api_urls', namespace='api')),
    url(r'^api/1.0/login/', include('accounts.apitoken_urls', namespace='apilogin')),

] +static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I added  `+static(settings.MEDIA_URL` ~ before ,my app worked well.
So,I didn't know how I can fix this.

Now I am making Serializer when users logged in my app.

In settings.py,I wrote

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'image')
MEDIA_URL = '/image/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably it should be like that after urlpatterns:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

if settings.DEBUG == True:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: @user7523656 can you share your related settings?

Comment: Is it meaning settings.py?Which part did u think?

Comment: @user7523656 I have just noticed that you are not using include for admin urls. Can you please try it first include(admin.site.urls)?

Comment: @user7523656 settings related to MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT

Comment: @user7523656  I think it is ok and the problem is not related with code you have provided.